# Android MotionLayout make app laggy when changing scalex and scaley in some devices

Tags: android, animation, android-motionlayout

I'm using **motion layout** in my project and here is the final result

[image: final result]

it looks **OK**, but **Animation** plays with **lag** in some devices

- **Animation** plays with lag in **old** devices *(Samsung j5 2016 & Samsung j5 2017 & HTC desire 820)*
  here is an old device record : [video file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ucnXWONejnssdlHSKN1qijL1UR03eKFj/view?usp=sharing)
- **Animation** works fine in the **emulator** and **new** devices *(Huawei p30 light &
  Samsung note 8)*

---

in `layout description`, `scaleX` and `scaleY` and `alpha` are changing

here is my **layout description** source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:duration="1000"/>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/mock_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/cv_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="0"
            android:alpha="1"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="0"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"/>


        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/v_activity_main_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/cv_content_shadow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/content_space"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/content_shadow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/content_space"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/mock_view"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/cv_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="0"
            android:scaleX="0.72"
            android:scaleY="0.75"
            android:alpha="1"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="0"
            android:scaleX="0.72"
            android:scaleY="0.72"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/cv_content_shadow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleX="0.62"
            android:scaleY="0.65"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/content_space"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/content_shadow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleX="0.62"
            android:scaleY="0.62"
            android:alpha="0.3"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/content_space"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/v_activity_main_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:scaleX="0.75"
            android:scaleY="0.75"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            motion:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            motion:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"/>

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Does any help to make animation without lag , please?
and again here is [video file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ucnXWONejnssdlHSKN1qijL1UR03eKFj/view?usp=sharing) that has lagged when the animation starts

Comment: I didn't find any solution and now, I'm using `ObjectAnimator` which solved my problem. but still, my question is that why `Motionlayout` lags in old devices

Comment: I have the same issue. On my nougat device, the animation is very choppy no matter what I tried. I installed the same app on device running android 9, and the animation is smooth as butter.